# App crashes in simulator alternately

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, ios-simulator, xcode4.6

Every time I run the app in simulator through Xcode, the app crashes alternately i.e. One time runs fine, next time crashes in simulator.

I also noticed that on quickly stopping/ starting the app through run/ stop buttons on Xcode almost always crashes the app in simulator. (I'm guessing that this has to do something with dealloc and alloc of app in simulator - which needs time to breathe before it can relaunch the app).

Comment: Without codes, how can we help ? Also, what is the crash log / exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by by choosing GDB debugger instead of LLDB. Here is steps:

1. Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme
2. Select Run
3. Selct Your Target
4. Now change your Debugger to GDB.

Comment: Thanks @manujmv. But since LLDB is what Apple is moving to, what are the tradeoffs we're looking at when switching over from default to GDB?

Comment: Marking this as accepted answer. LLDB seems to have lot of hidden issues for the time being and GDB still promises to be a stable big brother.